# Oracle 11g SQL - DD/MON/YYYY to MONTH DD, YYYY with WHERE month year clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, format

I'm trying to get records from orders placed in a certain month and year (February 2012).  The column containing that data (Dtordered) is currently in DD/Mon/YYYY format.  I need to display the date in MONTH DD, YYYY format. How would I go about this?  I know I will need to use a WHERE clause to get the records from the date and year. In pseudo, here's what I'm attempting.

```
SELECT Idbasket, Idshopper, Dtordered(MONTH DD, YYYY)
FROM bb_basket
WHERE Dtordered(Mon)='Feb' AND Dtordered(YYYY)=2012;
```

How would I correct my formatting and conditions? Am I even close?

Comment: What is the datatype of Dtordered?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Dtordered` is stored as a `DATE` (I hope so, as it's a date)

[if it's not, you'll have to use `TO_DATE(Dtordered, 'DD/Mon/YYYY')` whenever you need to work on `Dtordered`, but that's bad]

Use `TO_CHAR` to display a date in a given format.

You can use

`TO_CHAR(<yourdate>, 'YYYYMM')` = '201202' to get a year and month value.

or

```
EXTRACT(year from <yourdate>) = 2012 and EXTRACT(month from <yourdate>) = 2
```

so

```
SELECT Idbasket, Idshopper, TO_CHAR(Dtordered, 'MONTH DD, YYYY')
FROM bb_basket
WHERE TO_CHAR(Dtordered, 'YYYYMM')='201202';
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't have MONTH or YEAR function.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man oh, seems that's you're right, I'm mixing my dbms

Answer (score 0):

One tip very simple using [to_char](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) function, look:

For Month:

> **to_char**(YOUR_FIELD , 'MM') = 09

For Year:

> **to_char**(YOUR_FIELD , 'YYYY') = 2014

For Day:

> **to_char**(YOUR_FIELD , 'DD') = 25

For Description Month:

> **to_char**(YOUR_FIELD , 'MON') = 'FEB'

or

> **to_char**(YOUR_FIELD , 'MONTH') LIKE '%FEBRUARY%'

*to_char* funcion is suported by sql language and not by one specific database.

One adiction information. To get month description of atual date at oracle database:

> select **to_char**(sysdate,'MON') from dual; -- today returns SET

> select **to_char**(sysdate,'MONTH') from dual; --today returns SETEMBER

I hope help anybody more...

Abs!